# SQL Server query syntax analyzing

Tags: sql-server

I have the Northwind database:

[image]

and this query which I'm trying to analyze what it does:

```
 [ProductName] 

SELECT [ProductID],
FROM [Products]
WHERE [ProductID] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [ProductID]
                      FROM [Order Details])
```

I'm having a hard time understanding, what does the `[ProductName]` at the beginning mean? And it's impossible to execute it, is it even legal?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. This query won't execute. Perhaps you're not seeing the whole query?

Comment: That query does not even compile

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for this.

```
SELECT [ProductID],[ProductName] 
  FROM [Products]
 WHERE [ProductID] IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [ProductID]FROM [Order Details] );
```